# How to find actual concurrent thread is running in apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, tomcat6

My Production **Apache Tomcat Version : 6.0.10**. I have configured **maxThreads = 600** in Server.xml . I need to know what is the ***actual concurrent thread is running*** in my production server. Is there any monitoring tools or linux command available please share me.

Answer (score 3):

You can see `Current Threads` in real time from the Manager web application deployed on your Tomcat Server.

Just Login to Manager application using `server/manager`. Enter your credentials. Click `Server Status` in the top right. Then in the section `http-bio-(port)` you will see the information you are looking for like:

> Max threads: 200 Current thread count: 10 Current thread busy: 3 Max processing time: 80525 ms Processing time: 1569.449 s Request
>   count: 9736 Error count: 43 Bytes received: 2.98 MB Bytes sent: 13.18
>   MB

UPDATE

The information above show that the server can have a maximum of 200 threads at any point in time. There are 10 threads currently being used (10 sessions are currently being monitored by the web container. There are 3 threads that had activity the last few seconds.... )

Now in your question you mention the word `concurrent`. That is JVM and CPU specific and there is no mechanism in the Tomcat implementation that could answer your question.